# Fast Testing: How to load only part of active_model in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to get test a model without loading my entire Rails app.  I want to inlcude only the parts of rails relevant to the class I'm testing.  How do I require active_model/validations correctly?  I thought I had done it correctly, but the setup below throws this error:

```
undefined method `validate' for Project::Media:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Model being tested:

```
#app/models/project/media.rb

class Project::Media < Project  #Project inherits from ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :allowable_media_source

  before_save : classify_link

  #next, all the methods

end
```

Spec:

```
#spec/models/project/media_spec.rb

class ActiveRecord
  class Base; end
end

class Project; end

require_relative '../../../app/models/project/media.rb'
require 'active_model/validations'

describe Project::Media do
  #then tests 
end
```

Comment: This http://iain.nl/testing-activerecord-in-isolation might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is not working because `Project` (in your test) is not inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`, so it has no `validate` method. Requiring ActiveModel validations just makes the `ActiveModel` module available, you need to actually include it in your class to make its methods usable, like this:

```
class Project
  include ActiveModel::Validations
end
```

More on using ActiveModel in isolation in [this article](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/).

More refs:

- [4 Steps to Faster Rails Tests](http://tom-clements.com/blog/2011/10/23/4-steps-to-faster-rails-tests/)
- [Fast RSpec/Rails: Tiered spec_helper.rb](http://paul.annesley.cc/2012/03/fast-rspec-slash-rails-tiered-spec-helper-dot-rb/)
- [Fast Tests With and Without Rails](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/fast-tests-with-and-without-rails) (paid)

Comment: Thanks for all the references!  I dig it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to require what I needed, per Shioyama's post.  This is what it looked like.

```
require 'active_model'
require 'active_model/validations'
require 'active_record/callbacks'
class Project
  include ActiveModel::Validations    
  include ActiveRecord::Callbacks
end

require_relative '../../../app/models/project/media.rb'

#then tests
```